# Connection with JDBC to mssql is failing

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using below way to check the connection with eclipse and sql and I am using default database with windows authentication

```
import java.sql.*;
public class TestConnection {

    static final String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://MYPC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=master";
//master is the name of default database of sql server
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Done.");

    }

}
```

i am using sql server 2008 R2
and I getting an error "Connection link failure"

Error

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host MYPC, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: MYPC". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.Done

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:228)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5465)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:2151)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1903)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:623)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:15)
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace: use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`

Comment: I have never attempted connecting via Windows authentication.  Can you use a username/password instead?

Comment: Thank you for responding and I just want to setup a connection so both the connection types will work

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you for your response I have added the stacktrace in my question

Comment: And have you followed the instructions in the exception message? Specifically the instructions that say: _"Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host."_

Comment: from the control panel I have set the SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Browser to Automatic

Comment: Your latest update suggests that there is no machine with hostname `MYPC`. Use the correct hostname or IP address, or make sure the hostname is correctly setup in DNS or your local hosts file.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have tried everything I could to setup the connection and unfortunately nothing is working, this my office laptop and I don't have admin access on it and I don't have any username password for sql server, is there any chance I can create a connection on sql server without the admin access?